# Ant script exec

Tags: jenkins, ant, windows-console, ibm-integration-bus

I'm trying to automate build for my IBM Integration Bus applications. I'm using Jenkins and Ant to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="project" default="run">
<target name="run" description="">
    <property name="toolkit.home" value="C:\Program Files\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.10\server\bin" />
    <property name="cmd.home" value="C:\Windows\System32" />
    <property name="cmd.file" value="${cmd.home}\cmd.exe"/>
    <property name="iib.cmd" value="C:\Program Files\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.10\iib.cmd"/>
    <antcall target="build" />
</target>
<target name="build">
     <exec executable="${cmd.file}">
         <arg value="/k"/>
        <arg value="${iib.cmd}"/>
     </exec>
     <exec executable="mqsilist" newenvironment="false"/>
 </target>
 </project>
```

The first exec will set up the IIB build environment. The next exec will list all the Integration nodes installed on the machine. When the script is run, the second exec throws an error. "System can't find the specified file".

When I run the above commands in Powershell or cmd they work fine.

```
F:\Ant>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.10\iib.cmd"
F:\Ant>mqsilist
```

What I exactly mean to say is the build environment which the first exec sets is lost. I don't want ant to loose the build environment set by first exec. Tried using `newenvironment="false"`. It didn't work. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Jenkins runs as a separate user, so if `mqsilist` isn't available in its PATH, it won't be able to run that program. By the way, what is the point of your `run` target? You can just set those property defaults in `build` itself, or even at the root project level.

Comment: I'm new to Jenkins. How can I know under which user Jenkins is running. I'm the only user(admin) on my machine.

Comment: I think maybe you're focusing on the wrong thing. You need to add the programs you want to use to your PATH environment variable. Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System and you'll see an area for adding environment variables.